# How do you configure a root route in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I would like to create a route for `/` that loads another route, say 'posts'. It seems that the only two solutions are to configure Ember's `IndexRoute`:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {
    return this.transitionTo('posts');
  }
});
```

**OR**

Map our 'posts' resource to the `/` path:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  return this.resource('posts', { path: '/' });
});
```

The first solution does not seem reasonable because it always sends visitors to `/posts` instead of having an actual base path of `/`. The second solution does not seem reasonable because it *only* allows posts to be viewed from `/` and not `/posts`. The second solution inherently creates strange nested URLs like `/new` for a new post instead of `/posts/new`.

What is the most idiomatic way to configure `/` to load another route instead of redirecting, while still making the target resource available from its normal URL? In other words, I would like the `/` path to access posts, and still have posts available via `/posts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to go is to have your `IndexController` `needs` the `PostsController`, and then you can use `render` in your `index` template to render the posts.

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs : ["posts"]
});
```

And then your `index` template might just be

```
{{render 'posts'}}
```

Comment: This can work, but there are a few things that it requires. First it requires the `PostsController` be defined and not implicitly generated. It also requires that Ember's `IndexController`is an instance of `Ember.ArrayController` instead of `Ember.Controller`. Once those conditions were satisfied, it required that an `IndexRoute` be defined that fetched the model separately. Calling `{{render 'posts'}}` in the index template did not work but `{{partial 'posts'}}` did. One benefit is that the controller and template are reused, however the route and model fetching are duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is the following:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.get('store').findAll('post');
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this.controllerFor('posts').set('content', model);
  }
});
```

That way the controller for this route will be an `ArrayController` filled with all your posts. And you can still use your `/posts` route whichever way you like. By default this would be `App.IndexController` (which you can override to implement custom functionality).

Alternatively, if you wanted to use a different controller (say `App.PostsController`), you could specify that in the routes `renderTemplate` hook. So if you wanted to use your `posts` template and your `App.PostsController` used in your `App.IndexRoute`, you would include:

```
renderTemplate: function() {
   this.render('posts', { controller: 'posts' });
}
```

For more details have a look at the [routing section of the Ember.js guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/).

Comment: This way he'll also have to define the `renderTemplate` hook to make sure the proper controller (probably `PostsController` is used, not auto-generated one).

Comment: That's a good point, but really depends what he is trying to do. Thanks for pointing that out though, I'll edit my answer to make that clearer.

Comment: Thanks @chopper, setting the `model` and `controller` on Ember's `IndexRoute` works so long as I added `{{partial 'posts'}}` to the index template. However, this will use a generated controller instead of the `PostsController`. Alternatively, I implemented the `renderTemplate` hook you've provided and it uses the appropriate controller and template, but the template yields empty results in its `{{#each}}` block. It appears to be ignoring the `model` hook on the `IndexRoute`, however, it does render properties from the `PostsController`.

Comment: Whoops I just realized a mistake in my answer above. `controller` should be `setupController`. I edited the answer to reflect that. Give that a try and let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed this to `setupController`, but the same behavior appears to be happening when  the `{{#each}}` block is reached.

Comment: Whoops, the issue is that `setupController` was setting the content of `IndexController`, rather than the `PostsController`, but at the same time we were specifying the `renderTemplate` hook to use the `PostsController`. See the update to my answer - it should be `this.controllerFor('posts').set('content', model);`